# How to disable twitter bootstrap in some area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `twitter bootstrap`. `boostrap` declared in my `master page`. But i need some form do not use boostrap style.

How to stop boostrap into some `div` or `form`?

My target is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can devide your bootstrap CSS to 2 different CSS. The one will have the general CSS for all the website and the second one will have only buttons grids ... e.t.c . So Once you need it you just add the general CSS into your webpage or you remove it if you don't really need it

The general styles are between line 1-176 for bootstrap.css